# I can't decorate whole Controller with my Custom Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I try to decorate a full controller class like this:

```
namespace SisParkTD.Controllers
{
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public class AbonosController : Controller
    {
```

I can decorate the methods in the controller but can't decorate the full controller.

The error i get when i try to decorate the controller class is this:

> The attribute 'CustomAuthorize' is not valid on
>   this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method' declarations.
>
> Attribute 'SisparkTD.Filters.CustomAuthorizeAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. Is is valid on 'Method' declarations only.

Here is the code for the CustomAuthorizeAttribute:

```
namespace SisParkTD.Filters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            using (var db = new SpContext())
            {
                var controller = (string)httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
                var action = (string)httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
                var accion = db.Acciones.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Descripcion == action && a.Pagina.Descripcion == controller);
                var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                var usuario = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NombreDeUsuario == username);

                if (usuario == null) return false;
                if (accion == null) return false;
                var rolesId = db.RolesUsuarios.Where(ru => ru.UsuarioId == usuario.UsuarioId).Select(ru => ru.RolId);
                if (!rolesId.Any()) return false;

                foreach (var rolId in rolesId)
                {
                    if (db.Permisos.Find(rolId, accion.AccionId) != null) return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `AttributeUsage`.

Comment: I feel a little embarrassed, so much thanks SLaks

Comment: Don't be too embarrassed, I just did the same exact thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)] from the attribute. (credit to SLaks for the answer)